# Use of Unresolved Identifier 'PHAssetMediaTypeImage'

Tags: ios, swift, mime-types, photo, phasset

I am using PHAsset in swift. `PHAssetMediaTypeImage` is not resolved. Can anyone help.

[image]

Comment: Photo framework is already imported

Comment: `PHAssetMediaType.Image` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvable this way `PHAssetMediaType.Image` and `PHAssetMediaType.Video`

fetch all assets, then sub fetch only the range your need

```
    var assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions){

}
```

[also check apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetmediatype)

Answer (score 1):

In swift, `PHAssetMediaTypeImage` is just `.Image` and `PHAssetMediaTypeVideo` is just `.Video`:

```
if asset.mediaType == .Image {

}

if asset.mediaType == .Video {

}
```